# Advanced settings or alternative to Windows Filter Keys to filter millisecond keyboard gltches?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, windows-registry, accessibility

My laptops internal keyboard has developed a fault where it randomly spits characters into the input stream. Because of the way the laptop was built it's going to cost north of $300 to replace the keyboard (keyboard is not removable from laptop body) so as a stop gap I need to filter errant key presses - presumably since there at the hardware level filtering anything either without a matching key press release, or those that happen at super human speeds would do the trick... This is where FilterKeys would come in but unfortunately the interface only allows filtering delays in specific duration's and the minimum is 0.3 seconds which makes the keyboard all but unusable.

W&*-hat I am after is either a way of setting a finer grained filter in the millisecond range either via registry or`12356789-=/*-4 alternative software.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this [post from user Soarer](https://geekhack.org/index.php?topic=41881.0) I found the location of the registry keys required inside the source code posted (the compiled utility archived there also works and has allowed me to type this post without keyboard glitches).

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Control Panel/Accessibility/Keyboard Response]

- DelayBeforeAcceptance
- AutoRepeatDelay
- AutoRepeatRate
- BounceTime

all of which take values in millisecond units.

Comment: As the source code is available, although incompatible with modern Visual Studios, I tinkered a build into https://github.com/HQJaTu/Filterkeys-setter