# How can I specify custom values for the 'bounce keys' feature of filter keys in Windows 11?

Tags: keyboard, windows-registry, windows-11, accessibility, windows-11-v22h2

I've got some keys on my keyboard accidentally repeating and I've found that enabling bounce keys filtering does prevent that from happening, however, the 0.3 second delay is far too long for my typing speed and it is really slowing me down. I need to try other values like 200ms, 100ms or perhaps even 50ms, but there's no way to do this from the UI.

[image]

I tried some registry editing at `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response` as suggested in [some blog posts](https://davescomputertips.com/windows-10-quick-tips-fix-key-bounce/) and [forum threads](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c9fb8984-68a5-4482-b5a0-9d83d13e39fe/registry-keyboard-response?forum=w7itproperf), however, they are for Windows 10 or even Windows 7. These tweaks appear to have no effect on Windows 11 22H2, even after a full restart.

What is the correct way to enter custom values into this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/1629602/advanced-settings-or-alternative-to-windows-filter-keys-to-filter-millisecond-ke?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific value that needs to be changed for the bounce keys setting is, unsurprisingly, `BounceTime` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Accessibility\Keyboard Response`. However, settings lower than 150 appear to have a worse effect of slowing everything down.

As mentioned in one of the forum posts, this hardware problem is nearly impossible to fix via software, so I'm giving up and getting a new keyboard.